# How to view the subjects of a particular course

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of courses and in each course there is a buttonthat allows me to view all subjects of that particular course.

First, I used this command so laravel already know what the parent element is:

```
php artisan make:controller CourseSubjectController --model=Subject --parent=Course
```

In the course index.php file I have the button that should allow me to view all the subjects for that particular:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('departments.course.subjects.index', [$course->department->id, $course->id])}}">Subjects</a></td>
```

Apparently the url is correct:

The controller looks like this:

```
public function index(Course $course)
{
    return $course->subjects;
}
```

When I visit the link I encounter this error:

```
"Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\CourseSubjectController::index() must be an instance of App\Course, string given"
```

How can I view the subjects of the course?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws an error because you didn't pass a Course instance to your route. I assume you are using GET request and in your route you are only passing the course department id and its id :

```
[$course->department->id, $course->id]
```

So maybe you could do this in your controller instead :

```
public function index($departmentId, $courseId)
{
    $course = Course::findOrFail($courseId);
    return $course->subjects;
}
```

Comment: You are right @Pol. I should have passed one more parameter in the index function.
It works now and I appreciate the support